# Neo4j return all nodes and relationships that exist in certain subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to specify a node and return all the relationships that the node has, along with every other relationships that are connecting the rest of the nodes.

An example of what I would like to return is:

```
Eric, PARENT_OF, Mia
Eric, PARENT_OF, Peter
Mia, SIBLING_OF, Peter
Mia, SPOUSE_OF, Mark
...
```

Assuming that the specified node is `Eric`, they query should return all the relationships that are directly connected to him along with the relationships that are not connected to `Eric` but are connected to some of his connected nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have simulated your scenario with this data set:

```
CREATE (eric:Person {name:'Eric'})
CREATE (mia:Person {name:'Mia'})
CREATE (peter:Person {name:'Peter'})
CREATE (mark:Person {name:'Mark'})
CREATE (eric)-[:PARENT_OF]->(mia)
CREATE (eric)-[:PARENT_OF]->(peter)
CREATE (mia)-[:SIBLING_OF]->(peter)
CREATE (mia)-[:SPOUSE_OF]->(mark)
```

The below query should work to achieve your goal:

```
MATCH (root:Person {name:'Eric'})-[r*1..3]->(a:Person)
UNWIND r AS rs
RETURN DISTINCT startNode(rs).name, type(rs), endNode(rs).name
```

As result:

```
╒════════════════════╤════════════╤══════════════════╕
│"startNode(rs).name"│"type(rs)"  │"endNode(rs).name"│
╞════════════════════╪════════════╪══════════════════╡
│"Eric"              │"PARENT_OF" │"peter"           │
├────────────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"Eric"              │"PARENT_OF" │"Mia"             │
├────────────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"Mia"               │"SIBLING_OF"│"peter"           │
├────────────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"Mia"               │"SPOUSE_OF" │"Mark"            │
└────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Comment: Good, although I'd recommend performing the DISTINCT operation before instead of after the projection of results: `... WITH DISTINCT rs RETURN ...`